# How to set a look up field value to null/blank in access 2010?

Tags: forms, ms-access, null, field, lookup

I need some help with Access 2010 forms. My form has a number of fields (from one table). One of the field is a logical field. If the user selects true, then the next field (text field) should be enabled. This is working fine - I created an after update event procedure. The problem I have is if the user accidentally selects true, and then selects a value/s for the text field (the text field looks up a query - it is a look up field and it can have more than one value - the user can select/check as many from the list and they will be stored to the text field, separated by coma).

How will I set the text field (look up field) value to blank, if the user goes back and set the logical field to false? me.textfield.value = null gives an error.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is the control (text field) bound to a look-up field in a table? If so, are you using Sharepoint? If it is not bound to a look-up field, how does it get these comma separated values and why? It is against the rules of database design to have more than one value per field (column).

Comment: How does one select multiple values for a text field? Are you using a ListBox to populate the text field? Try `me.textfield.value = ""` either way.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that in fact a multi-value column is in fact a normalized data table.

So the display looks like this:

[image]

To clear the records selected in this child table, which is your mult-value selection, you can use this code behind the above button:

```
  Dim rstChild      As DAO.Recordset

  Set rstChild = Me.Recordset.Color.value

  Do While rstChild.EOF = False
     rstChild.Delete
     rstChild.MoveNext
  Loop

  Me.Color.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to insert a blank lookup field is to select the field in design view and click on the lookup tab in the field properties. Before the first entry in Row Source insert the following " ";